# How do I sort dynamically generated columns in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a dashboard that will display partition stats for an Impala table. The table can have zero or more partitioned columns on it. Because of this, I ended up representing the partitioned columns as a list of name value pairs. The data looks a little like this:

```
<ArrayOfPartitionStats>
  <PartitionStats>
    <Files>1</Files>
    <Partitions>
      <Partition>
        <Name>applicationname</Name>
        <Value>app1</Value>
      </Partition>
      <Partition>
        <Name>date</Name>
        <Value>2015-10-25</Value>
      </Partition>
    </Partitions>
  </PartitionStats>
  <PartitionStats>
    <Files>1</Files>
    <Partitions>
      <Partition>
        <Name>applicationname</Name>
        <Value>app2</Value>
      </Partition>
      <Partition>
        <Name>date</Name>
        <Value>2015-10-25</Value>
      </Partition>
    </Partitions>
  </PartitionStats>
</ArrayOfPartitionStats>
```

I want to take each of those partitioned columns and set the name as the column header and the value as the entry in the table and have each of the columns be sortable.

```
|applicationname|date      |files|
+---------------+----------+-----+
|app1           |2015-10-25|1    |
|app2           |2015-10-25|1    |
```

Right now I'm generating the table with this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sortable col-md-2" ng-repeat="partition in partitionStats[0].partitions" ng-click="setOrder(partition)">
        {{partition.name}}
        <span ng-show="orderColumn == partition && !orderReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
        <span ng-show="orderColumn == partition && orderReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
      </th>
      <th class="sortable col-md-2" ng-click="setOrder('files')">
        Files
        <span ng-show="orderColumn == 'files' && !orderReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
        <span ng-show="orderColumn == 'files' && orderReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="partition in partitionStats | orderObjectBy:orderColumn:orderReverse">
      <td ng-repeat="partitionHeader in partition.partitions | orderBy: orderColumn:orderReverse">{{partitionHeader.value}}</td>
      <td>{{partition.files | number:0}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And my controller function:

```
$scope.setOrder = function (column){
        if (column == $scope.orderColumn) {
            $scope.orderReverse = !$scope.orderReverse;
        } else {
            $scope.orderColumn = column;
            $scope.orderReverse = false;
        }
    }
```

The problem that I'm running into is what to pass into the setOrder function for Angular's orderBy to sort on that column. Right now I pass in the object reference, but that does not sort correctly. Any ideas how to reference this column for orderBy?

Comment: may be this is what you want to do https://github.com/Zizzamia/ng-tasty, demo http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/directive/table/simple

Comment: I think you should try ng-repeat="thing in list track by SOME_ATTRIBUTE_OF_THING". SOME_ATTRIBUTE_OF_THING has to be unique, you can call a function to set an id from 0 to nb_elements - 1, with the order you want.